# Do you need to unsubscribe from @Output EventEmitter

Tags: angular, typescript

On the Angular website they have an example of a Parent and Child component talking to each other using `@Output() onVoted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`. See below.

In this given example, do you need to unsubscribe from the EventEmitter to prevent memory leaks/bloat? Or does the Framework take care of that for you?

**component-interaction/src/app/voter.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-voter',
  template: `
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <button (click)="vote(true)"  [disabled]="voted">Agree</button>
    <button (click)="vote(false)" [disabled]="voted">Disagree</button>
  `
})
export class VoterComponent {
  @Input()  name: string;
  @Output() onVoted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  voted = false;

  vote(agreed: boolean) {
    this.onVoted.emit(agreed);
    this.voted = true;
  }
}
```

**component-interaction/src/app/votetaker.component.ts**

```
import { Component }      from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vote-taker',
  template: `
    <h2>Should mankind colonize the Universe?</h2>
    <h3>Agree: {{agreed}}, Disagree: {{disagreed}}</h3>
    <app-voter *ngFor="let voter of voters"
      [name]="voter"
      (onVoted)="onVoted($event)">
    </app-voter>
  `
})
export class VoteTakerComponent {
  agreed = 0;
  disagreed = 0;
  voters = ['Mr. IQ', 'Ms. Universe', 'Bombasto'];

  onVoted(agreed: boolean) {
    agreed ? this.agreed++ : this.disagreed++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you see example on the Angular website and they don't unsubscribe then why do you think you should do it?

Angular takes care about it.

When it creates directive instance it subscribes to the outputs:

```
if (def.outputs.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < def.outputs.length; i++) {
      const output = def.outputs[i];
      const subscription = instance[output.propName !].subscribe(
          eventHandlerClosure(view, def.parent !.nodeIndex, output.eventName));
      view.disposables ![def.outputIndex + i] = subscription.unsubscribe.bind(subscription);
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/235a235fab45b2c82f8758fc9c0779f62a5b6c04/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L138-L140

and when it destroyes component it also automatically unsubscribes from output subscriptions:

```
export function destroyView(view: ViewData) {
  ...
  if (view.disposables) {
    for (let i = 0; i < view.disposables.length; i++) {
      view.disposables[i]();
```

So every time you destroy your directive angular will dispose all subscription for you.

But if you subscribe to `EventEmitter` manually in code then you have to unsubscribe yourself.

Comment: The documentation is often wrong. The HttpClient documentation demonstrates manually subscribing to an HttpClient response with no explicit unsubscribe. If your component is destroyed while your http request is in flight this will result in a handler in your destroyed component atttempting to handle the request, with unexpected and likely erroneous consequences.

Answer (score 1):

i think you don't have to do unsubscribe. Since You are not using child to parent component iteration for fetching data from API there is no need to unsubscribe.