# Does Angular automatically remove template event listeners?

Tags: angular

In my template I have `click` events listeners attached:

```
<a class="link-component" href="{{displayURL}}" (click)="handleClick($event)">
```

I know I could use HostListener's, or Renderer2 as follows:

```
 this.clickListener = this.renderer.listen(this.htmlElement, 'click'........
 this.clickListener();
```

But, just in relation to the `template` bound event handlers, will they be removed automatically when the component is destroyed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When angular creates view nodes it [listens to element outputs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/core/src/view/element.ts#L177-L190) such as `click`, `focus`, `change` etc. and adds disposable callback
 to `disposables` array of current view
[image]

Now when it's time to destroy view angular just [runs all disposable callbacks](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L505-L514)

```
export function destroyView(view: ViewData) {
  if (view.state & ViewState.Destroyed) {
    return;
  }
  execEmbeddedViewsAction(view, ViewAction.Destroy);
  execComponentViewsAction(view, ViewAction.Destroy);
  callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst(view, NodeFlags.OnDestroy);
  if (view.disposables) {
    for (let i = 0; i < view.disposables.length; i++) {
      view.disposables[i]();  <================================
    }
  }
  ...
```

So this way angular will remove all listeners of current view.

[image]

See also:

- [Do you need to unsubscribe from @Output EventEmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759538/do-you-need-to-unsubscribe-from-output-eventemitter)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, everything you bind on template will be destroy with the component. Binding with `@HostListener` will be removed too. Only event listened manualy with `addEventListener` or derived syntaxe won't be removed automaticaly.

Comment: How do you know this is the case for events bound in the template may I ask?

Comment: I have probably read it among all the articles about deep Angular behavior. Since there is no way to remove a listener bound this way, you can be sure Angular takes care of it properly. Because if it won't, it will be such a huge issue for the whole framework.