# Complete Output() eventemitter in ngOnDestroy callback

Tags: angular

Is it a good practice to call the complete() method for each Output() EventEmitter in my angular component's ngOnDestroy callback? 
That way any subscription made to those outputs would end straight when the component is destroyed. And in most cases, I would not have to worry about unsubscribing anymore in parent components. What do you think?

**Example**

I have a parent component that subscribes to an output event of a child component.
I usally do:

```
childCompoment.event.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.parentComponentDestroyed$), // end subscription when parent is destroyed
  ).subscribe((eventData: any) => {
    // do stuff
  });
}
```

Now if the child component gets destroyed, that does not end my parent subscription automatically. I have to wait until the parent component is destroyed itself.
If i call event.complete() in the child components' OnDestroy callback then my subscription will end as soon the child component is destroyed.
What is the best approach in that case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759538/do-you-need-to-unsubscribe-from-output-eventemitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I personally feel that it's not really necessary to call `complete()` on the `@Output` `EventEmitter`. I'm saying that because it's up to us to call `emit` from the Child Component.

It's similar to not calling `unsubscribe` on an `Observable` `Subscription` that is returned from `HttpClient` in cases it's just called once.

Here's an [**amazingly enlightening article by Ben Lesh**](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) who's Rxjs lead. Reading this article will make it clear of when to `unsubscribe` and when not to.

You can think about the idea of calling `complete()` on similar lines.

**UPDATE:**

The example added by you exhibits an extremely rare use-case when the `ChildComponent` was used inside the Parent Component Typescript class, probably using `ViewChild` and it's events were listened to in the Parent Component. In this particular scenario, I think it would be important to `unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy`.

But in most of the cases, the Child Component's `@Output` events are generally listened to by a handler in the Parent Component. And the events fired from a Child Component are generally in our hands. And if the Child Component is destroyed, then it won't really fire any events, so I don't really think there's a need to explicitly call `complete` or `unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: thanks for the reply and for the great article. I understand that it's our responsibility to unsubscribe from the parent component. I have updated my question with an example. Which approach would you take in this example?

Comment: indeed, in my scenario the parent is a list component and the children are list items retrieved by `@ContentChildren`. Since i am using virtual scroll, the children are constantly destroyed and recreated as i scroll. If i don't end the subscription as soon as an item is destroyed. i can end up with hundreds of 'passive' subscriptions (for items already destroyed) that will only end when my list component is destroyed. Hence my initial question to complete the child `EventEmitter` in the component `ngOnDestroy`. so that would make sense for this particular case? thanks!

Comment: @dalox, yeap. That makes total sense.

Comment: Terrible, wrong answer. Not unsubscribing from an incomplete Subject WILL leak the subscriber. The only reason why you don't need to unsubscribe from @Outputs and HttpClient observables is because Angular automatically completes them.